# How put an element in a regex only if another element is present

Tags: regex

I need to handle the long pattern to check if input number follow my pattern. The long ca be:

```
1000.00
1000
1000.0
1.00
10
```

the int part is not a limit on the number of  digit, but the decimal part has can be at most two digits. I use this regex:

```
^[0-9]+(,|.){0,1}(00){0,2}$
```

this regex work for 99% of input, because if I pass this value `100.` , the regex takes this value. Anyone can help me to modify this regex in such way that the user put the `.` must put the fraction part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(,|.){0,1}` matches an optional `,` or any char (an unescaped `.` outside of a character class matches any char but linebreak char(s)) and then `(00){0,2}` can also match an empty string (zero, one or two `00` substrings).

You need

```
^[0-9]+(?:[,.]0{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gg7tHu/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[,.]0{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[,.]` - a comma or a dot (the dot needs no escaping when inside a character class)
  - `0{1,2}` - 1 or 2 zeros
- `$` - end of string.